# Are null values allowed in any column of a table in SQL?

Tags: null, sql-standard

I have doubts over null values.Therefore can you please explain me briefly what is a null value in sql and can we use null values at any place in sql tables?

Comment: Strictly speaking null is not a value, it is the absence of a value. If a column is declared as not null, you have to provide a value for it.

Comment: @Lennart OK but the SQL standard refers to them as "null values".

Comment: @ybercubeᵀᴹ I don't think that implies that we should treat them as values. In that sentence I would interpret `null values` as a  synonym for `missing values` or `unknown values`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Allowing Null Values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189265(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Columns defined with a PRIMARY KEY constraint or IDENTITY property
>   cannot allow null values.
>
> The nullability of a column determines whether the rows in the table
>   can contain a null value for that column. A null value, or NULL, is
>   different from zero (0), blank, or a zero-length character string such
>   as "". NULL means that no entry has been made. The presence of NULL
>   typically implies that the value is either unknown or undefined.

[Microsoft SQL Server's definition of NULL:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx)

> A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL
>   is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are
>   equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any
>   other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.
>
> Null values generally indicate data that is unknown, not applicable,
>   or that the data will be added later. For example, a customer's middle
>   initial may not be known at the time the customer places an order.

SET ANSI_NULLS setting can change the behavior of NULL.  In future versions this setting will be ON by default and you will not be able to turn it off.
Details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql

This is an article which go in depth about NULL.
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/

Few example of NULL in TSQL [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823893/Handling-NULL-in-T-SQL).

Comment: @I_am_feminist Note that this answer is for SQL Server, not for "SQL" - especially the part about "ANSI NULLs". Other DBMS might behave differently.